# difficult to understand function definition

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, currying

```
cube (x,y,z) =
  filter (pcubes x) cubes


cubes = [(a,b,c) | a <- [1..30],b <- [1..30],c <- [1..30]]


pcubes x (b,n,m) = (floor(sqrt(b*n)) == x)
```

so this code works, `cubes` makes a list of tuples,pcubes is used with filter to filter all the cubes in which `floor(sqrt(b*n)) == x` is satisfied,but the person who has modified my code wrote     `pcubes x` in `filter (pcubes x) cubes`,how does this work.`pcubes x` makes a function that will initial the `cubes x (b,n,m)` that will take in a tuple and output a bool.the bool will be used in the filter function. How does this sort of manipulation happen? how does `pcubes x` access the `(b,n,m)` part of the function?

Comment: Currying - http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you are confused sbout. Which `x` where?

Comment: hold on ill edit the question

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing the question so that it is clearer what you expect the code to do. Also I suggest you add type signatures. They might point out weird things like `cube` being of type `[(a,b,c)]` while `cubes` is also `[(a,b,c)]`. While this might be intended, I fail to find any intuition behind the piece of code (I do not say that means anything).

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, we don't usually use tuples (ie: `(a,b,c)`) to pass arguments to functions. We use *currying*.

Here's an example:

```
add a b = a + b
```

Here `add` is a function that takes a number, the *returns another function* that takes a number, then returns a number. We represent it's type as so:

```
add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)
```

Because of the way `->` behaves, we can remove the parentheses in this case:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

It is called like this:

```
(add 1) 2
```

but because of the way application works, we can just write:

```
add 1 2
```

Doesn't that look like our definition above, of the form `add a b`...?

---

Your function `pcubes` is similar. Here's how I'd write it:

```
pcubes x (b,n,m) = floor (sqrt (b*n)) == x
```

And as someone else said, it's type could be represented as:

```
pcubes :: Float -> (Float, Float, Float) -> Bool
```

---

When we write `pcubes 1` the type becomes:

```
pcubes 1 :: (Float, Float, Float) -> Bool
```

Which, through currying, is legal, and can quite happily be used elsewhere.

I know, this is crazy black functional magic, as it was for me, but before long I guarantee you'll never want to go back: curried functions are useful.

---

*A note on tuples: Expressions like `(a,b,c)` are* data *. They are not purely function-argument expressions. The fact that we can pull it into a function is called*  pattern matching, *though it's not my turn to go into that.*